# An equality regarding conditional expectation and Markov Chains

Tags: probability, markov-chains, conditional-expectation

Let $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}_0}$ be a Markov Chain on a discrete state space $S$ and transition semigroup $P = (p(x,y))_{x,y\in S}$. Let $C\subset S$ and let $k\in \mathbb{N}$. I'm supposed to check that the following equality holds, or correct it so that it does hold

$$P_x(X_1\notin C,...,X_k\notin C ) = P_x(X_1\notin C)\ \prod\limits_{j=2}^k 
E_x[P_{X_j}(\hat{X}_1\notin C)1_{\{X_j\notin C\}}]  $$

with $\hat{X}\sim X$. So far my computations tell me that something is wrong here. For instance, for $k=2$.

$$
P_x(X_1\notin C, X_2\notin C ) = \sum_{y\notin C}\sum_{z\notin C}P_x(X_1=y,X_2=z)\\
= \sum_{y\notin C}\sum_{z\notin C}p(x,y)p(y,z) \\ = \sum_{y\notin C} p(x,y) P_y(X_1\notin C) \\
= E_x[P_{X_1}(\hat{X}_1\notin C)1_{\{X_1\notin C\}}]\\
= P_x(X_1\notin C)\ E_x[P_{X_1}(\hat{X}_1\notin C)|X_1\notin C] 
$$
It is pretty close to what was expected, but not the same. For $k=3$, what I get is even further from what is expected:

$$
P_x(X_1\notin C, X_2\notin C,X_3\notin C ) = \sum_{y\notin C}\sum_{z\notin C}P_x(X_1=y,X_2=z)\\
= \sum_{y\notin C}P_x(X_1=y, X_2\notin C,X_3\notin C )\\
= \sum_{y\notin C}P_x(X_1=y, X_2\notin C,X_3\notin C )\\
= \sum_{y\notin C}P_x(X_2\notin C,X_3\notin C| X_1=y)p(x,y) \\
= \sum_{y\notin C}P_y(X_1\notin C,X_2\notin C)p(x,y) \\
= \sum_{y\notin C}\sum_{z\notin C} p(y,z) P_z(X_1\notin C)p(x,y) 
$$

The last inequality holds using the computations for $k=2$.

In summary, I don't know how to get a result similar to the claimed equality. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mentioned that your task is to "check that the following equality holds, or correct it so that it does hold" -- but then you proceed as if it's a problem that it seems false. Might it be that you just need to repair it instead?

Comment: It is a problem indeed, for two reasons: a) It becomes a more difficult problem (as I see it) b) This equality comes from a bigger problem, in which it would be much more useful to prove it right.

Comment: I agree with your implicit assessment that the stated formula is wrong, though I'm admittedly not sure how to repair it (yet). What do you need in the repaired version? Is it important that it be expressible as a product?